# How can pass FormData in native HTTP with ionic 3 @ionic-native/http?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have added plugin in ionic 3 project

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http@4
```

I want to pass FormDate in native HTTP post request.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileObject)
formData.append('temp_id', '');
let headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "api-auth": 'apiAuthToken String',
  "User-Auth": 'userAuthToken String'
  }
this.http_native.setDataSerializer('urlencoded');
this.http_native.setHeader('*', 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http_native.post('url String', formData, headers).then(api_response => {

});
```

**Error**: `advanced-http: "data" argument supports only the following data types: Object`

Comment: Please post all error from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object in the second parameter of post method. The object will be automatically converted in form-url-encoded as you set -

```
this.http_native.setDataSerializer('urlencoded');
```

Remove:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileObject)
formData.append('temp_id', '');
```

Replace With:

```
var formData = {
    file: fileObject,
    temp_id: ''
 }
```

And finally make post request:

```
let headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "api-auth": 'apiAuthToken String',
  "User-Auth": 'userAuthToken String'
  }
this.http_native.setDataSerializer('urlencoded');
this.http_native.setHeader('*', 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http_native.post('url String', formData, headers).then(api_response => {

});
```

**If you want to upload file then check this documentation - https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#uploadfile**

Comment: Thank you @Piash for reply. But i have already passed  'formDate' as object but  http_native.post is convert each type into string..I am not want to call fileUpload plugin for file . I want to call only one plugin http_native.post Which is not working for object